# How to rename a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I want to use for two very similar actions (like and unlike). I am sure that I need to rename something, but after searching online I couldn't find something seemingly so obvious. Any help is greatly appreciate.

Script I want to rename:

```
<script>
$(function() {
// get into the habit of caching the elements you will be re-using
var error = $('.error');

$('.button').click(function () {
    error.hide();

    // cache all the elements we'll be using
    var contactForm1 = $(this).closest('.contact_form1'),
        likesid = contactForm1.find('input[name=likesid]'),
        likerid = contactForm1.find('input[name=likerid]');
        unlikestatus = contactForm1.find('button1[name=unlikestatus]');

    if (likesid.val() == '') {
        // ...
        likesid.focus();
        return false;
    } 
    if (likerid.val() == '') {
        // ...
        likesid.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // easier to use object rather than string
    // not sure where likestatus came from so it is ommitted
    var data = { likesid: likesid.val(), unlikestatus: unlikestatus.val(), likerid: likerid.val() };

    // short-hand method for $.ajax with POST
    $.post('simpletest.php', data, function (res) {
        // the rest
        contactForm.html('<h5 class="message" style="color: #4EB44B;">unliked</h5>')
    });

    // no need to do any return false
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You want to rename a function or a script?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm very new to javascript. I'm looking for anything that would allow me to use this same code twice by only changing a few things

Comment: Pass them as argument to your function

Comment: I'll research javascript arguments, thank you

Comment: You've pasted a mess of javascript, if you had two messes of javascript, what would you want to be different between them?

Comment: probably due to the fact that I am a beginner at this language...

Comment: What are the things that would "change"?

Comment: the button name, instead of "unlikestatus" it would be "likestatus"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear but assuming you just need to pass the button attributes to identify which button was clicked, you can do it via the button itself.

**Javascript function:**

```
$(function() {
  $(".buttonClassName").click(function() {
    //Method 1 to retrieve custom data from the button
    alert($(this).attr("data-somedata"));
    //Method 2 to retrieve custom data from the button ( newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)
    alert($(this).data("somedata"));
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class="buttonClassName" data-somedata="someTestDataFromButton1">Like</button>
<button class="buttonClassName" data-somedata="someTestDataFromButton2">Dislike</button>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qpLoh3tz/1/

Comment: is it possible to change --- $('.button').click(function () { --- so instead of referring to ".button", I can refer to a class or id of the button?

Comment: In this context, ".button" is the class name of the button, you can have any name you want.

Comment: I've updated the class name above and the fiddle for better understanding. If you want to use the id, then wrap the logic inside a function and call the function when either of the button is clicked.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!